randomized left stochastic matrices: two by two right multiplied by two by one as an average
I'm looking at the identity matrix and its inverse right multiplied by two by one matrix [1,0] and two by one matrix [0,1].  Choosing either is a fifty fifty chance.
If I simply right multiply and alternate both unique cases, is that then the average of responses possible?
